# bash and env: something: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions

I use openSuse Leap 42.1.

I had installed Skype long time ago. And it worked all the time. But recently it stopped start and when I run it from terminal I receive an error:

```
env: /usr/lib/skype/skype: Permission denied
```

I had googled this error but no luck.
Now I have installed new version of Android Studio and when it runs and download SDK and tools it said:

```
Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool
```

I went to terminal again and run `mksdcard` in it and get an error:

```
bash: ./mksdcard: Permission denied
```

My last installation of the previous version of the Android Studio was successful. I have tried install previous version now and get this error too.

I consider that these errors have one nature. But all my research don`t bring me success.

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: "Permission denied" means that, for some reason, the file couldn't be executed.  Please include the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/skype/skype` and `ls -l ./mksdcard`.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-- 1 paola users 11819 Mar 22  2014 ./mksdcard`

Comment: is your home directory NFS mounted by any chance ? Please provide output from `df -h ${HOME}`

Comment: `/dev/sda3        54G   18G   37G  33% /home`

Comment: Maybe the drive is mounted with no execute permissions?  Try `grep " /home " /proc/mounts`.  And the same for whichever filesystem is shown by `df -h /usr/lib/skype/skype` .

Comment: What's the output of `file -L /usr/lib/skype/skype ./mksdcard` ? Did you perform any updates or make some configuration changes recently? Especially changes that might affect a security framework such as SELinux, or that might affect 32-bit application support? Does anything appear in the system logs when you try to run a program? What is the output of `ls -lF /lib/ld-linux.so.2` ?

Comment: @JigglyNaga: `/dev/sda3 /home xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0`
 and for **df -h /usr/lib/skype/skype** `/dev/sda2        50G   24G   26G  48% /`

Comment: @Gilles: `/usr/lib/skype/skype: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=6eef9a3f7c9719980b6e317a00ea971d3717ac89, stripped` and `./mksdcard:           ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped`. Yes, of course, I install common system updates  usually. `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jul 11 16:06 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.19.so;5783540f`

Comment: Does the problem affect all 32-bit programs? The information about `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is hard to read because of your shell alias, please run `/bin/ls -lF /lib/ld-2.19.so`

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 152308 Jul  4 21:19 /lib/ld-2.19.so*`

Comment: `strace skype` should provide a lot more debug information about your problem. Could you attach a log?

Comment: @MayeulC, I finally moved to fedora and have no problems with `skype` anymore. but thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, it really sounds like a *[Permission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix))* error. Have you checked the executables you are trying to run?

```
ls -l /usr/lib/skype/skype
```

This should output the permissions of the file (Read, Write, eXecute), respectively for the user, the group it belongs to, as well as the other users.

Since you are getting this error on more than one occasion, it sounds more like a group issue. You may for some reason no be a member of a required group. To tell what groups you are part of, you can use the `groups` command.

Of course, this is just an hypothesis.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36499124 Jul 28 18:36 /usr/lib/skype/skype`

Comment: Strange, the permissions look fine. It might be related to a file/folder skype (maybe mksdcard too) tries to access, so it may be related to the permissions in your home folder.

Comment: If it were easy I would have solved it myself )

Comment: Sure, but you can never know what has already been tried if not provided with ample details in the first place :) I've been trying to reproduce the issue on my side, without success for now.